# Loop for Object Count Not Running Enough Times

Tags: ios, for-loop, parse-platform, nsarray, pfobject

I could use some help troubleshooting this.  I use Parse.com, and do a query to return all objects from one of the Parse classes.  I do this when the view Appears using the code below.  When I run it, the console log shows there are 8 objects, so I would expect the code to run 8 times, one for each object.  However, it only runs 3 times.  What am I missing?

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Share"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            NSLog(@"Objects%lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);

            for (int i=0;i<[objects count];i++)
            {

                PFObject * obj = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
                self.theObject = obj;
                //Continue running code for each of the items in PFObject

            }


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];



}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps modifying the array while you are looping through it? Or perhaps modifying the loop counter `i`? We really need to see what else might be in the for loop.

Comment: Please check that all your objects in the array are valid maybe one of them is corrupted